# Singly Linked List insert function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure

I am trying to insert into linked list but I am not getting proper output when display() method is called. Everything is fine while inserting data into the linked list.

The printf statement in insert() method prints :

```
a int 
b int
c int
```

But when display() method is called it prints :

```
c 
c
c
```

Datatype member of the structure doesn't get printed at all. And, I think identifierName member gets overwrite every time. Following I snippet of my code :

```
struct symbol
{
    char* identifierName;
    char* datatype;
    struct symbol* next;
};

void insert(struct symbol** headRef,char* identifier,char* type)
{
    struct symbol* newnode = (struct symbol*) malloc(sizeof(struct symbol));
    newnode->identifierName = identifier;
    newnode->datatype = type;
    newnode->next = (*headRef);
    (*headRef) = newnode;
    printf("%s %s\n",newnode->identifierName,newnode->datatype); //debugging
}

void display(struct symbol* node)
{
    while(node!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s %s\n",node->identifierName,node->datatype);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: The bug is most likely in the call to `insert`. Show your whole code.

Comment: What did you find out when you ran it under your debugger?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to make copies of the strings passed as arguments of the function.

Change the function the follwoing way

```
#include <string.h>

//...

void insert(struct symbol** headRef,char* identifier,char* type)
{
    struct symbol* newnode = (struct symbol*) malloc(sizeof(struct symbol));

    if ( newnode )
    {
        newnode->identifierName = malloc( strlen( identifier ) + 1 ); 
        strcpy( newnode->identifierName, identifier );

        newnode->datatype = malloc( strlen( type ) + 1 );
        strcpy( newnode->datatype, type );

        newnode->next = *headRef;
        *headRef = newnode;

        printf("%s %s\n",newnode->identifierName,newnode->datatype); //debugging
    }
}
```

Take into account that the function expects that paramameters identifier and type are pojnters to first characters of strings.

If for example parameter identifier is a pointer to a single character then instead of

```
        newnode->identifierName = malloc( strlen( identifier ) + 1 ); 
        strcpy( newnode->identifierName, identifier );
```

you have to write

```
        newnode->identifierName = malloc( sizeof( char ) ); 
        *newnode->identifierName = *identifier;
```

Also do not forget to free memory pointed to by these pointers when a node is deleted.

Answer (score -2):

replace these two lines

```
newnode->next = (*headRef);
(*headRef) = newnode;
```

with

```
newnode->next = headRef->next;
headRef = newnode;
```